# How to make *sh lines shorter

Tags: zsh

I recently encountered a line of `zsh` code

```bsh
ls_colors_parsed=${${(@s.:.)LS_COLORS}/(#m)\**=[0-9;]#/${${MATCH/(#m)[0-9;]##/$MATCH=$MATCH=04;$MATCH}/\*/'=(#b)($PREFIX:t)(?)*'}}
```

Not only does this burn my eyballs, it's far, far over the 80 char limit. Unfortunately, I don't see any clear way to shorten it. I have many lines like this (made of ridiculously complicated substitutions that can't be cut into pieces). What is the canonical way of handling lines like these if I want them to be <80 chars long.

Comment: You do `\\n` anywhere.

Comment: The canonical way is to write lines that are longer than 80 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break long lines by *escaped newlines*, that is `\` immediatelly followed by a newline:

```
ls_colors_parsed=${${(@s.:.)LS_COLORS}/(#m)\**=[0-\
9;]#/${${MATCH/(#m)[0-9;]##/$MATCH=$MATCH=04;$MATC\
H}/\*/'=(#b)($PREFIX:t)(?)*'}}
```

**WARNING**

While you can break a line that way nearly everywhere, there are exceptions. It will not work inside single quoted text or after the `\` of an escape sequence (`\n`, `\x40`, ...). Some other shell constructs may break, too: If you put try to break between `($PREFIX` and `:t)` in your example, it will not work correctly.

Comment: And if you are using indentation, it might not work exactly like you expect in some situations.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That's right. Indentations are essentially just a bunch of spaces. So you can indent only in places where you could write the same amount of spaces in the single line version of the code: between words (as recognized By the shell)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
setopt extendedglob
alias 'verbose{{=read -rd "" -u9 _code 9<<-"}}";\
  eval "${_code//[[:space:]]#$'\''\n'\''[[:space:]]#}"'

verbose{{
  ls_colors_parsed=${
    ${(@s.:.)LS_COLORS}
      /(#m)\**=[0-9;]#
      /${
          ${MATCH
            /(#m)[0-9;]##
            /$MATCH=$MATCH=04;$MATCH
          }
            /\*
            /'=(#b)($PREFIX:t)(?)*'
      }
  }
}}
```

The newlines surrounded by spacing characters are removed before being passed to `eval` for interpretation.

Comment: Thanks, this could be useful, but has two shortcomings: 1. It's slower (uses a subprocess) and 2. It breaks substitutions that actually use whitespace (like `${param/ /`)

Comment: @PythonNut, good point. See the edit for an alternative that addresses those.